# Не индексирует и не коммитит измененный файл

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

Имеется проект, который также синхронизируется с удаленным репозиторием на github.com.

В этом проекте было произведено изменение нескольких файлов, после чего изменения были добавлены в индекс с помощью пункта меню Add to Index. После этого был сдалан Commit and Push. Всего измененных файлов было 5 штук. По четырем из них вышеописанная процедура прошла успешно, пятый файл не попал в этот список. Более того, если делаю Compare With.. и сравниваю с Branch, Tag or Reference, разницу в файлах он показывает, а при Add to Index и Commit and Push говорит, что No changes, и сохранения не происходит. Я посмотрел, в .gitignore этого файла там нет. Более того, недавно он нормально сохранялся. Вообще такое периодически бывает.

Скажите, в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить все эти операции из командной строки. Если удастся, то это значит, что проблема в графическом интерфейсе git, если нет, будет конкретное сообщение об ошибке.

```
git add path/to/my/file
git status
git commit -m "SomeCommitMessage"
```

Также укажите используете ли вы Git на Windows, OS X или Unix/Linux.

Помимо `.gitignore` есть ещё  файл `.git/info/exclude`. Также файлов .gitignore может быть несколько (в разных каталогах). Ещё в принципе может быть дополнительный глобальный gitignore для всех репозиториев, но это нужно специально настраивать.